# Different font size in front page and when I open post in Blogger

Tags: html, css, fonts, blogger

I have a very weird problem that I didn't have in the past. The font size of body post in the front page of my blog seems exactly as I want but when I open the post, the text becomes really small. I 've tried to change .post-body font size but it seems to have effect only on the front page. I also noticed that the font size inside the post is the same as postmeta-primary. What can I do?
If you want to have a look my blog is http://yourlostnfoundpets.blogspot.gr/

Comment: Looks fine to me on Firefox.. Often this type of problem stems from nested percentage font sizes - are you using any percentage font sizes?

Comment: what technology are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#container #span2 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">Normal Front Page text<br>
    <span id="span1" style="font-size:small;">Blog post page text (small)</span><br>
    <span id="span2" style="font-size:small;">Blog post page text CSS override to match front page text size</span>
</div>
```

Seems that the culprit is that your main body text on a post's page is wrapped in the following:

```
<span style="font-family: inherit; font-size: small;">
...
</span>
```

Is this added automatically by your blog's CMS? The `font-size: small;` inline CSS is over-riding your CSS stylesheet.

You could overwrite the inline style by adding this to your CSS stylesheet to use the same font size you specified for your front page:

```
.post-body span {
    font-size: 15px !important
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to use relative font sizes as opposed to fixed pixels, e.g. 1.5em